# How can I increase the computational efficiency for dealing with numpy arrays using loops in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, processing-efficiency

I am trying to do some image transformation tasks with numpy in python. The idea is that, suppose I have loaded an image file into a numpy array `img`, then I create an new array `new_img`, and also define a mapping between the pixel coordinates: `[x,y]` in the new image corresponds to `[old_x,old_y]`. And then I use `new_img[x,y] = img[old_x,old_y]` to compute the transformation. The loop to actually compute this transformation looks likes this **(not really runnable because I omitted a lot of details regarding the transformation rule, width and length of the images, boundary check, etc., but you get the idea)**.

```
def get_old_coord(y,x):
  # this is the function to compute the corresponding pixel coordinates
  # some computation here yields old_x and old_y
  # ...
  return old_x,old_y

for x in range(height_of_new_img):
  for y in range(width_of_new_img):
    new_img[y,x] = img[get_old_coord(x,y)]

# new_img is then as desired.
```

The problem I've encountered is that the double loop is extremely time consuming. It takes one or two minutes for images that are 1000x1000. On the other hand, since the transformation rule `get_old_coord` can be a lot of things, I don't think I can imporve this by using some built-in function for array arithmetics. How can I make this process more efficient?

---

**Update:** for those who want a complete example, here is one

```
import math
import torch
import torch.nn
import torchvision
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_old_coord(x,y,old_h,old_w,new_h,new_w):
    cent_x, cent_y = new_h/2, new_w/2
    if ((x+1)%200==0 and (y+1)%new_w==0) or (x+1==new_h and (y+1)%new_w==0):
        print('Progress = %.2f %%'%((x+1)/new_h*100))
    rel_x, rel_y = x-cent_x, y-cent_y
    #print('Doint %d,%d, center = %d,%d, rel_x, rel_y = %d,%d'%(x,y,cent_x,cent_y,rel_x,rel_y))
    rho = math.sqrt(rel_x**2+rel_y**2)
    rho /= (min(new_h,new_w)/2)
    if rel_x==0 and rel_y>=0:
        theta = math.pi/2
    if rel_x==0 and rel_y<0:
        theta = -1*math.pi/2
    if rel_x>0:
        theta = math.atan(rel_y/rel_x)
    if rel_x<0:
        theta = math.atan(rel_y/rel_x)+math.pi
    theta = 2*math.pi-theta
    rho = 1-rho
    old_x = (int)(rho*old_h)
    old_y = (int)(theta*old_w/(2*math.pi))%old_w
    old_x = min(old_h-1,max(0,old_x))
    #old_y = min(old_w-1,max(0,old_y))
    #print('rho = %f, theta = %f, old_x, old_y = %d,%d'%(rho,theta,old_x,old_y))
    return old_x, old_y

def transform(new_h,new_w,old_im):
    old_h, old_w, _ = old_im.size()
    new_im = torch.zeros(new_h,new_w,3).int()

    for i in range(new_h):
        for j in range(new_w):
            new_im[i,j] = old_im[get_old_coord(i,j,old_h,old_w,new_h,new_w)]

    return new_im

input_file_name = 'in.jpg'
output_file_name = 'out.jpg'

new_h = 800
new_w = 800

old_im = torch.tensor(plt.imread(input_file_name))
new_im = transform_radial(new_h,new_w,old_im)

new_im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(new_im))
new_im.save(output_file_name)
```

Basically, this implements a polar coordinate transformation. Sorry for not having time yet to add comments into my code. But trying it on any of your images should be fun. Also, I am actually using torch tensors in this example, but they are not much different from numpy arrays.

Comment: Using `for loops` on Numpy array doesn't support vectorization. Try to do everything using Numpy array methods...You can increase a lot of *computational efficiency*.

Comment: What you describe is called time complexity. You might want to study. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Without "get_old_coord" using numpy functions (or similar) there is not much to do. If the output of the function solely depends on the input, memoization can be an option. Maybe also numba or cython can help but I don't know enough about these.

Comment: If you could provide some examples of "transformation rules" you might be using, we might be able to help you better

Comment: @Ch3steR I wish I could. But as I stated, the `get_old_coord` doesn't really allow me to do so.

Comment: @TheFool I know about time complexity. But I bet that the same loop written in C would be much faster. And I am asking how I can achieve the same efficiency here.

Comment: @G.Anderson I have provided a workable example in my edited question.

Comment: With `math` functions you code only works with scalar inputs - one pixel at a time.  You are stuck with that slow pixel by pixel iteration.  In some cases you can rewrite the function to work with the whole array, using `np.tan` etc and masking to replace the `if`.  Another option is to write/compile the function with `numba`, letting it do the iteration in fast compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is vectorization, but with access to index of the array on which the element wise operation is being done on.

for an NxM array, I found a way of doing this as

```py
N,M = 4,6 # random number of dimensions

foo_mat = np.random.rand(N,M) #<-- random array representing data

def bar_func(elem, i, j): # <-- i,j are the indices of the matrix 
    return pass #<- Do whatever you want here

bar_func = np.vectorize(bar_func, signature="(n,m),(n,m),(n,m)->(n,m)")

baz_solved_mat = bar_func(foo_mat, *np.mgrid[:N,:M])
```

#### How does it work?

```py
bar_func = np.vectorize(bar_func, signature="(n,m),(n,m),(n,m)->(n,m)")
```

Here, signature says, for (n,m) shaped elem values matrix, (n,m) shaped i values and (n,m) shaped j values (3 params of the `bar_func` resp.) return `(n,m)` shaped value. This maps each i,j coordinate of 3 matrix together.

`np.mgrid` is a quick way of getting these arrays of row and column index. [see doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)

Comment: `np.vectorize` is **not** a speed tool.  It is slower than more explicit Python loops.

Comment: Normally `np.vectorize` passes scalar values to the function (e.g. on pixel value and coordinates).  So it's a way of replacing a double `i,j` iteration (but not faster).  But with that signature, it passes 2d arrays to the function.  Put a `print` in `bar_func` to see that.  With 2d array inputs like this, your `np.vectorize` does not improve the functionality, and runs 6x slower.  Test and time your answer for yourself.